# Array of object count occurence and return object

Tags: javascript

I want to count all occurrences for date and group them, then count all hours of these date with a count.

Here is my array:

```js
var array = [{ date: '2021-04-28', hours: '05:30' },
  { date: '2021-04-28', hours: '05:30' },
  { date: '2021-04-28', hours: '03:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-05-04', hours: null },
  { date: '2021-05-05', hours: null }
]
```

It should return an object :

```
var object =  {
       2021-04-28 : {
       count : 3, // count
       hours : {
       05:30 : 2,// count
       03:00 : 1
       }
      },
      2021-04-20 : {
       count : 3, // count
       hours : {
       10:00 : 3,// count
       }
      },
      2021-05-04 : {
       count : 1, // count
       hours : null
      },
      2021-05-05 : {
       count : 1, // count
       hours : null
      },
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code you have developed. Stackoverflow is not meant to give you complete solutions for your problems

Comment: You can use reduce() to solve your problem.

Comment: const countAppearance = ({ arr }) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, c) => {
      if (typeof a[c] === "undefined") a[c] = 0;
      a[c]++;
      return a;
    }, {});
  };

  const ca = countAppearance({
    arr: array
  });

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed for not being focused, it's literally just asking one question. While it's not a good question, it's definitely "focused".

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-brook-0w8gc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It's seems you're not wanting an answer to a question but more a «please code this for me». Provide some example about how you tried to implement this and we could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert your array to the desired output:

```js
const array = [
  { date: '2021-04-28', hours: '05:30' },
  { date: '2021-04-28', hours: '05:30' },
  { date: '2021-04-28', hours: '03:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-04-20', hours: '10:00' },
  { date: '2021-05-04', hours: null },
  { date: '2021-05-05', hours: null }
];

const result = array.reduce((a, {date, hours}) => {
  a[date] = a[date] || {count: 0, hours: {}};
  a[date].count++;
  a[date].hours[hours] = a[date].hours[hours] || {count: 0};
  a[date].hours[hours].count++;
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```